# model returning null array

Tags: codeigniter, model

i have a model named Student_model and fetchDataPro function inside the model

```
class Student_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function fetchDataPro($from,$to)
    {   
            $query=$this->db->select(['signuppro.id','fname','lname','cname','profile_pic'])
            ->from('signuppro')
            ->join('course','cid=course.id')
            ->limit($from,$to)
            ->get();
            $result=$query->result();
            print_r($result);exit;
    }
}
```

It's printing a null array. I think i had writter wrong something related limit because if i remove the limit it's returning me proper data

Comment: did you try `last_query()`?

Comment: thank you i have to right $to first and then $from

Answer (score 0):

Say something more like this

```
      <?php 
class Student_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function fetchDataPro($from,$to)
        {   
                $query=$this->db->select(signuppro.id,fname,lname,cname,profile_pic')
                ->from('signuppro')
                ->join('course cid','cid.id  = signuppro.id_course','inner')
                ->limit($from,$to)
                ->get();
                $result= $query->result();
                return $result;
        }
    }
```

Check your join it has an error on the fields to attach

a+